# ldap authentication in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ldap, npm, openldap

I am trying to authenticate LDAP user using the below code. The code was working fine in Node v10.X. I have migrated my app to **Node v4.1.1** where I am not able to install **ldapjs** npm.

> Can someone help me with any LDAP npm which works in Nodev4.1.1

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');

function authDN(dn, password, cb) {
  var client = ldap.createClient({url: 'ldap://YOUR_SERVER:PORT'});

  client.bind(dn, password, function (err) {
    client.unbind();
    cb(err === null, err);
  });
}


function output(res, err) {
  if (res) {
    console.log('success');
  } else {
    console.log('failure');
  }
}

// should print "success"
authDN('cn=user', 'goodpasswd', output);
```

Comment: If you are not able to install ldapjs then provide installation steps here.